# .htaccess RewriteEngine breaks CSS/ Images

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I successfully was able to rewrite my dirty urls to clean urls but this broke my image and style folders too :(

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /www/index.php?page=$1&cmd=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Look in your firebug - you should see some 404 errors. The error should show you the path it is looking in for your images. Can you provide that please?

Comment: Yup, you will need to adjust the path to your images and style folders.

Comment: firebug (and the source code says it's looking for the CSS files exactly the place where they are kept

Comment: Yes, but your Apache will rewrite that place, e.g. `http://example.com/css/style.css` turns into `http://example.com/index.php?page=css&cmd=style.css`

Answer (score 5):

Add the follwing rewrite conditions to prevent rewriting of URLs that lead to existing files and directories, e.g. your JS, CSS and image files.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /www/index.php?page=$1&cmd=$2 [L]
```

If your images still don't show up, it's probably because you're including images like this: `<img src="./img/myimage.png" />`. If you now point your browser to `http://site.com/page/hello/`, your browser will be looking here for the image: `http://site.com/page/hello/img/myimage.png`. However, the image is actually here: `http://site.com/img/myimage.png`.

So you'll have to include your images like this: `<img src="/img/myimage.png" />` (everything after the domain).
This will force the browser to look ìn the correct place. (Assuming that your directory structure is like this.)

Comment: Sorry, I think I forgot to add a space between `FILENAME}` and `!`.

Comment: You're beautiful and I love you!

Comment: Spoke too soon. Images not linked in the CSS are broken now :(

Comment: This could also be security issue. You can still get to pages like /www/secret.php. Which I am guessing you don't want that right?

Comment: Otherwise, this is a good solution. It's what codeigniter does.

Comment: Also there is an issue where someone goes to www.domain.com/page there is an error but www.domain.com/page/ works :(!

Comment: @middus. that issue with the images still didn't work. So now I have the full URL for each image :(

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your styles are going to index.php too now. What I mean is

```
/styles/myStyle.css -> /www/index.php?page=styles&cmd=myStyle.css
```

So you should probably fix this by only rewriting some URLs. Like something like this?

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /www/index.php?page=$1&cmd=$2 [L]
```

Comment: this change just broke everything

Comment: This changes the structure of the URLs.

Comment: @Middus. What do you mean? what does ^pages/ do?

Comment: He assumes you want your URLs to look like this `http://www.yoursite.com/pages/a/b`. I don't think that's what you want. Look at my answer, that solution should do the trick without changing the structure of your URLs.